# Pass array of values and filtering object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to filter object by passing arrays of values in javascript

How to pass array of values  as arguments and filter the object using javascript.
Based on `send` and `receive` with `id`, get the object value in javascript.

for `id` trans, if `send` (in) is `bank` and `receive` (out) is `bank`, 
for `id` fund, if `send` (in) is `credit` and `receive` (out) is `bank` and
for `id` insta, if `send` (in) is `debit` and `receive` (out) is `bank`, get result obj

```
var send=['bank', 'credit', 'debit'];
var receive = ['bank', 'bank', 'bank'];
var id=['trans', 'fund', 'insta'];
var result = getSample(sample,send, receive, id);


I have tried but got stuck
function getSample(sample,sn, rcn, id){
  const temp = sample.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3)
    var selectval= temp.filter(x=>x.in==scn && x.out==rcn && x.id == id);
   return selectval;
}
```

```
var sample =
  [{
    "btob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10,
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "insta",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
    "ctob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "insta",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
   "dtob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "insta",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
}]
```

```
Expected Output:
  result=[
    {
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10,
    },
    {
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "id": "insta",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What did you try to accomplish such?

Comment: @briosheje thanks for reply,I have to get the object as shown by passing arrays of values to function

Comment: @Murali Nepalli thanks a lot for answer, but am getting id.map is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare arrays id,send,receive and sample, Then run the below code.

```
const temp = sample.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3);
var jointArray = id.map((currentValue, index) => {
  return id[index]+"-"+send[index]+"-"+receive[index];
});
var result = temp.filter(function(item) { 
   return ( jointArray.indexOf(item.id+"-"+item.in+"-"+item.out)!=-1  ) 
});
console.log(result);
```

here is js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/qcxntpfy/